# Convert Unicode Emoji to NSString (Not \ue415 format)

Tags: ios, unicode, hex, emoji

I am trying to convert an emoji to an NSString.  I previously asked a question on how to do the opposite (convert an NSString to a unicode) at [NSString to Emoji Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662336/nsstring-to-emoji-unicode).  I thought perhaps it would be best to ask this as a new question here.

How can I convert an NSString containing an emoji () to an NSString containing a unicode in this format (U0001F603)?

This question is basically the reverse engineering of the solution from the previous page.  The catch is the project does not use the \ue415 format, but rather the U0001F603 format.

Edited per comment:
2014-07-11 11:37:19.448 emoticon[******] unicode:

```
unicode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\\UFE0E", unicode];
```

2014-07-11 11:37:19.449 emoticon[******] unicode: \UFE0E

**SECOND COMMENT RESPONSE** 
I'm not entirely sure if I follow what you mean by I didn't add the first line of code.  I hope I haven't been unclear.  To try and be more specific on what I would like, I logged your code in, and then logged what I wish to get:

```
NSString *first = @"";
NSString *second = @"\\UFE0E";
NSString *third = @"U0001F603\\UFE0E";

2014-07-11 12:00:45.815 emoticon[******] first: , second: \UFE0E, third: U0001F603\UFE0E
2014-07-11 12:00:45.816 emoticon[******] desiredString: U0001F603
```

My hope is to produce the desiredString by converting the emoji to the desired string.

**THIRD COMMENT RESPONSE** 
[image]

Comment: Oh! Wait! Is `%@\ `  the emoji code for that icon, and you're generating that icon based on that? (Am away from my Mac at the moment, that's why I can't try it myself and asking instead).

Comment: Yes, the %@ contains the actual  emoji in it. It is the  that I am trying to convert into a raw NSString.  The variable unicode is of NSString.  I would like for the conversation to allow the variable unicode to be logged as U0001F603 rather than .

Comment: Ok. I get you now. Let me think about it...

Comment: You're adding two back-slashes between the character codes. Add only one.

Comment: It will not allow me to use one \ unless I am using a unicode such as \ue415.  Attaching a screenshot up above.  I'm really sorry for the trouble and lack of any clarity on my part.

Comment: Hmm... I should check this myself. Hopefully I'll have some time to do so tomorrow. (:

Comment: See! I edited my answer below, the issue was the formating of the character and adding the four zeros after `U` fixed that error, however this is not changing anything. Can you just provide an example input and output for what you want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 5: How to convert an Emoji to a unicode character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635393/ios-5-how-to-convert-an-emoji-to-a-unicode-character)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is using the *escape character* `\U0000FE0E` to the end of all Unicode characters to make it skip the emoji and display the proper Unicode character.

Here's the code:

```
@""        //This shows the colorful emoji icon.
@"\U0000FE0E"  //This shows the good old Unicode character.
```

You can also add it to the character code:

```
@"U0001F603\U0000FE0E"
```

Comment: Thanks, but at this point I am already able to make the emoji.  What I am trying to do is code it so an existing emoji is converted back into a raw NSString.

Comment: That's just what I explained. If you add `\UFE0E` to your existing emoji, it'll revert it to a Unicode char.

Comment: Where do you add this? Edit your answer and show the code there, please.

Comment: See my comment above. I think I'm confused now! Also I think you haven't added the first line of your code.

Comment: Updating question again with new code.  Man this is getting ugly haha.  I'll clean it up nicely if we can figure the answer out.

Comment: Still seems to not be working in the way we would expect.  Using         NSLog(@"%@\U0000FE0E", unicode); produces the emoji ︎ rather than a string.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. However I think I'm missing something from your question. That code would skip the colorful emoji and will display the unicode alternative, like the black and white icon, where you want to get the string behind it. However I imagine you have the string in the other format like `ue415`, don't you?

Comment: I have actually found another work around for the issue (by "re-architecting" the backend). I know this isn't the StackOverflow way, but perhaps we should drop this question. You have been nothing sort of super amazing though, so for (i = 0; i < awesome; i ++) { thank you! }

Comment: Jeremy , can you point me to your solution? I am having the same problem.   Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a *"pseudo-code" <sub>(JavaScript, you can run it in your browser's console)</sub>*  ..for opposite-direction.

```
String.fromCharCode(
((0x1F603 - 0x10000) >> 10) | 0xD800
,
((0x1F603 - 0x10000) % 0x400) | 0xDC00
)

=>>""
```

### Just **reverse the bytewise operations**, and *zero-pad it*.

---

#### If you are a programmer it should be more than easy for you.

[*..give a man a fish...*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)

<sub>source: [JavaScript Ninja - Easy Unicode Emoji Generator](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/unicode-emoji-generator/)</sub>